# Binding angular directive attribute to controller with jasmine and bindToController true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a directive using karma and jasmine. I'm using angular 1.4 and I searched different things here in SO and throuhg internet but I can't make it work.

```
var angular = require('angular');

module.exports = angular.module('myApp.ui.apps.servicesObject.list', [])

.directive('servicesObjectList', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {
            services: '=',
            selectedServices: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/ui/apps/services/directives/services.html',
        controllerAs: 'servicesListCtrl',
        controller: 'ServicesListController'
    }
})

.controller('ServicesListController', require('./servicesListController'));
```

This is how I'm trying to test it.

```
describe('Service app test, listDirective' , function(){
    var element, scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module('templates');
        angular.mock.module('myApp.ui.apps.servicesObject.list', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('gettextCatalog', { getString: function(){}});
            $provide.value('translateFilter', function(){});
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $controller){
        scope = $rootScope;
        scope.services= _servicesMock_;
        element = '<services-object-list selected-services="[]" services="services"></services-object-list>';

        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        controller = $controller('ServicesListController', {$scope: scope});
        console.log(controller.getServices());            
    }));

    it ("First test", function(){
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The problem that I have is that services is not binding in my controller, only in the scope. What I'm doing wrong? If I do console(controller.getServices()). It returns me undefined instead of the services that I pass as attribute. My production code is working as expected but not tests.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours I just discover a new feature added in angular 1.3 to make binding in unitTesting easier. Here is the thread of the discussion https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9425

Basically a third argument is added to the controller constructor service where you can pass the data that is bind to controller.

So the unitTest configuration will be like this.

```
describe('Service app test, listDirective' , function(){
    var element, scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module('templates');
        angular.mock.module('myApp.ui.apps.servicesObject.list', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('gettextCatalog', { getString: function(){}});
            $provide.value('translateFilter', function(){});
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $controller){
        var data = {
            services: _servicesMock_
        };
        scope = $rootScope;
        scope.services= _servicesMock_;
        element = '<services-object-list selected-services="[]" services="services"></services-object-list>';

        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        controller = $controller('ServicesListController', {$scope: scope}, data);
        console.log(controller.getServices());            
    }));

    it ("First test", function(){
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```